# $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{1-|z|}$ implies $|f'(z)| \leq \frac{4}{(1 - |z|)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

> Suppose that $f$ is analytic in the unit disk and $|f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{1-|z|}$. Prove that $|f'(z)| \leq \frac{4}{(1 - |z|)^2}$ in the open unit disk.

I am not really sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $z, |z|=r, 0 \le r <1$

The idea for this is to apply Cauchy on a disc centered at $z$ of some radius $\rho < 1-r$ so it is contained in the unit disc and then minimize the estimate on $\rho$ to find best such.

Concretely $2\pi if'(z)=\int_{|w-z|=\rho}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2}dw$, and since $|f(w)| \le 1/(1-|w|) \le 1/(1-(r+\rho))$ on the integration circle by hypothesis (as $|w| \le r+\rho$ there) while $|dw/(w-z)^2|=1/\rho$ we immediately get:

$|f'(z)| \le \frac{1}{(1-(r+\rho))\rho}, 0 < \rho < 1-r$.

A simple AM-GM inequality (or calculus or pick your favorite method) shows that $\frac{1}{(1-(r+\rho))\rho}$ is smallest when the two terms in the denominator are equal, or $\rho=\frac{1-r}{2}$, giving by substitution precisely that:

$|f'(z)| \le \frac{4}{(1-r)^2}=\frac{4}{(1-|z|)^2}$ so we are done!

Comment: Very impressive

Comment: happy to be of help - it is an interesting question how sharp the constant $4$ in there is